# Java Memory issue for huge CSV file

Tags: java

I am developing a system which loads a huge CSV file (with more than 1 million lines) and saves into database. Also every line has more than one thousand field. A CSV file is considered as one batch and each line is considered as its child object. During the time of adding objects, every object will be saved in List of single batch and at some point I am running out of memory as the List will have more than 1 million objects being added. I cannot split the file into N numbers since there is dependency between the lines which are not in serial order(any line can have dependency to other lines).

Following is the general logic:

```
Batch batch = new Batch();

while (csvLine !=null ){
   {
      String[] values = csvLine.split( ",", -1 );       

      Transaction txn = new Transaction();
      txn.setType(values[0]);       
      txn.setAmount(values[1]);

      /*
        There are more than one thousand transaction fields in one line
      */


      batch.addTransaction (txn);
}

batch.save();
```

**Is there any way we can handle this type of condition with the server having low memory?**

Comment: Do you upload each line directly to the DB or do you really save the 1 mio lines and then add it all to the DB?

Comment: @Blobonat I am adding 1 millions records in batch and then adding it all into the DB at once.

Comment: Are *all* lines dependent on each other, or are there groups? If it's the latter, can the groups be resolved by keeping in memory only a part of each line's information?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Not all the lines are dependent on each other, usually 5 records are dependent on each other identified by one field (txn_number). And the complex part is that these dependent lines are not in serial order.

Comment: @SushilPaudel If there is no other way then hold all data in memory you have to buy more memory to solve this issue. Or you change the structure of the CSV file in the way you are able to process only parts of the lines at one time.

Comment: @SushilPaudel How do you recognize that a line is dependent on another line? Is there a numerical identifier or something similar?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Yes, there is identifier (txn_number) to recognize the dependency.

Comment: What database? I always used materialized views in oracle to bulk load the CSV - then used the database to process the data

Comment: Have you tried to implement a preProcess() routine that sorts the lines by txn_number before actually processing the file?

Comment: @walen Would it be a good idea to sort the lines by txn_number for more than one million record?

Comment: @SushilPaudel Yes. As you said before: _"Not all the lines are dependent on each other, usually 5 records are dependent on each other identified by one field (txn number). And the complex part is that these dependent lines are not in serial order."_ So if ordering one million records means that later you can process just the first 5 records, then the next 5 and so on... then yes, absolutely sort the file first.

Answer (score 1):

In the old times, we used to process large quantities of data stored on sequential tapes with little memory and disk. But it took loooong time!

Basically, you build a buffer of lines than can fit in your memory, browse all file to resolve dependencies and fully process those lines. Then you iterate on next *buffer* until you have processed all file. If requires a full read of the file per each buffer, but allows to save memory.

There may be another problem here, because you want to store all records in a single batch. The batch will have to require enough memory to store all the records, so here again you have a risk to exhaust memory. But you can again use the good old methods, and save  many batches of smaller size.

If you want to make sure that everything will be either fully inserted in database or everything will be rejected, you can simply use a transaction:

- declare transaction at the beginning of your job
- save all your batches inside this single transaction
- commit the transaction when everithing is done

Professional grade databases (MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc.) can use rollback segments on disk to be able to process one transaction without exhausting memory. Of course it is **far slower** than in memory operations (not speaking if for any reason you have to rollback such a transaction!) but at least it works unless you exhaust the available physical disk...

Answer (score 0):

Dedicate **a separate database table just for the CSV import**. Maybe with additional fields for those cross-references you mentioned.

If you need to analize CSV fields in java, **restrain the number of value instances by caching**:

```
public class SharedStrings {
    private Map<String, String> sharedStrings = new HashMap<>();

    public String share(String s) {
        if (s.length() <= 15) {
            String t = sharedStrings.putIfAbsent(s, s); // Since java 8
            if (t != null) {
                s = t;
            }
            /*
            // Older java:
            String t = sharedString.get(s);
            if (t == null) {
                sharedString.put(s, s);
            } else {
                s = t;
            }
            */
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

In your case, with long records, it might even make sence to **GZipOutputStream** the read line, as bytes, to a shorter byte array.
But then a database seems more logical.

Answer (score 0):

The following will possibly not apply if you are using all fields of a csvLine.

String#split uses String#substring, which in turn does not create a new string but keeps the original string in memory and references the respective portion.

So this line would keep the original string in memory:

```
String a = "...very long and comma separated";
String[] split = a.split(",");
String b = split[1];
a = null;
```

So if your are not using all data of the csvLine you should  wrap every entry of values in a new String, i.e. in the above example you would do

```
String b = new String(split[1]);
```

otherwise the gc is unable to free string a.

I ran into this while i was extracting one column of a csv file with millions of lines.